# How to get PagesController back (accidentally deleted)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and was trying to create a new page, when I somehow (and I don't know where or when) the PagesController got deleted. So I created another one in the controllers folder

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
    end

    def about
    end
end
```

And now this error message pops up:

```
Template is missing: Missing template pages/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}
```

What did I do and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you can't see the trash to recover the files that you deleted or try "ctrl + z" (in windows) or "cmd + z" (in mac) to undo the deletion then you would need to create the files from the scratch, i'm assuming that you don't have code in those files.

Just go to the terminal, go to the project folder in the terminal and write this command:

```
rails g scaffold_controller pages home about
```

With that you will recreate the files that you deleted and keep the files that you didn't delete, as you can see with the command you are creating just the controller and the "home" and "about" views. This will not create the model, so you should be calm about that.

I hope it helps :D

Comment: @nmares12 i am glad that i was helpful, i will appreciate an upvote to my answer if it was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You have no `app/views/pages/home.*` template. You need to create that file. It will (probably) need a `.html.erb` extension, but that depends on which template language your using.

Comment: Just saw that I don't have app/views/pages but only app/views/layouts so I guess I somehow deleted that too and need a home and about page. I'll do that and see if it works, thanks!

Comment: @nmares12 ... Use whatever you *normally* use to create folders. Finder or Windows Explorer or the command line or *whatever*. It's just a *folder* on disk, identical to any other folder in your computer.